# Unknown items in a scroll view

Tags: android

I got an interesting problem for you this time. I have an online app on android that I have to update. They want to place the discounts on the main page, "Dispensary Info" as I named it and for now it is in a `scrollview`. The problem is that I don't know how many products are in a dispensary(they have more dispensaries) and I don't know how many of them have discounts. Their number variate. There are 3 solution that I can see as a junior programmer:

1. To generate `textviews` programmatically.
2. To make a `listview` with an adapter starting only with the second element.
3. To make a table.

None of those solution I know how to use...

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dispensaryPicture"
            android:layout_width="1000sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarDispensaries"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryStateAndZipcode"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView14"
            android:progressTint="@color/valet_hop_gold"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispensaryName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryPicture"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispensaryAdress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryName"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispensaryStateAndZipcode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryAdress"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryAdress"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispensaryRaiting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryStateAndZipcode"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryStateAndZipcode"
            android:text="Raiting:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispensarySchedule"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ratingBarDispensaries"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBarDispensaries"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispensaryDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryRaiting"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensarySchedule"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="FIRST TIME PATIENT DEAL"
            android:textColor="@color/valet_green" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTimeDeal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/writeAReview"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryName"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pencil"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dispensaryStateAndZipcode"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:text="Write a review"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/writeAReview"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView14"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the `xml` file. I think it would be easier to understand if you place this into a project and see for yourselves how the page is set for now.

Comment: If you have several (unknown count) of items to display and they are all alike, a ListView would be the way to go.

Comment: I thaught about that aswell, but I already have some items inside this xml file and I don't know if it is a good idea to use a listview inside a scrollview.

Comment: No a list inside a scroll view is not a good idea. But normally it should not be necessary. Can you make the extra stuff also list elements (of a different type)

Comment: I really can't! They asked me to place all inside the scrollview. So I place the discounts after all these information.

Comment: So my hands are tied.

Comment: The scrollview is a simple solution. I am familiar with it, but they asked something whole different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListView inside `NestedScrollView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- some views -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- some views -->

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I see where you are knocking, but is not what I am looking for. I am trying to find out how to insert a photo to get the idea. I don't know if I start to explain, you will understand(because of my swamp English)